# auto.arima extracts different results in Window and Linux

Tags: r, linux, windows, arima

The auto.arima() in package "forecast" give me different results in Window and Linux, like this ([snapshot of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dF04.png)):

```
data = c(8637.50,9160.00 ,9162.50 ,7850.00 ,8862.50 ,9175.00 ,9233.33 ,10050.00 , 12362.50 ,12637.50 ,15666.67 ,18566.67 ,24260.00 ,21887.50 ,13362.50 ,10825.00 ,8337.50 ,9050.00 ,8668.75 ,10833.33 ,12675.00 ,9700.00 ,8825.00 ,9675.00 ,10470.00,10346.75)
DATA = ts(data,frequency = 12)
auto.arima(DATA)
```

this is the result in **Linux(CentOS 7)**: ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]
[image]

this is the result in **Windows**: 
ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean
[image]

So can you tell me how can i do? I need to work under Linux.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try putting in the actual code instead of screenshots - it's much easier for people to work with

Comment: @rubadubdubr the code is right there

Comment: Running your code on my Windows R 3.4.4, I get an `ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]` model. Please, share the output of `SessionInfo()` of your R on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, I used different versions of the package under the different OSs, and, the package "forecast v8.3" has some changes to how ARIMA models are selected. "ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]" is in v8.3 and "ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean" is in v8.2.